# Finding the limit of a complex function $f(z)$ expressed in terms of $x$ and $y$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the limit as $z$ approaches $1-i$ of the complex function $$f(z) = x + i(2x + y)$$

What's confusing me is the way the function is expressed.  I have thought about simply plugging my real part into $x$ and imaginary part into $y$ but that doesn't give me the desired answer, unless my notes from class are wrong.

I apologize for the easy question but we have a bad teacher and no official book.  Also YouTube wasn't helpful.

Comment: plugging the real part in for x and the imaginary part in for y is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is obviously continuous so $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = f(z_0)$.

Therefore $\lim_{z\to 1-i} f(z) = f(1-i) = 1+i(2-i) = 2+2i$.